# MVC,Html.ActionLink,WebGrid,Linq,model,view,controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have a (webgrid) that it has a delete field with (Html.ActionLink), now I want return id value(linkDelete variable) to controller, but it has error.

View:

```
<div id="tblGrid">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @wb.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gTable", columns:
            wb.Columns(wb.Column("کد", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id.ToString())),
                wb.Column("Date", "تاریخ"),
                wb.Column("Name", "نام"),
                wb.Column("Email", "ایمیل"),
                wb.Column("Tel", "تلفن"),
                wb.Column("Status", "وضعیت بررسی"),
                wb.Column(header: "ویرایش", format: (item) =>
                {
                    var linkEdit = Html.ActionLink("تغییر", "Edit", new { ID = item.ID });
                    return linkEdit;
                }),
                wb.Column(header: "حذف", format: (item) =>
                {
                    var linkDelete = Html.ActionLink("امحاء", "Delete", new { ID = item.ID });
                    return linkDelete;
                })
            )
        )
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int linkDelete)
{
    var m = db.Contacts.First(j => j.ID == linkDelete);
    db.Contacts.DeleteOnSubmit(m);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete method parameter name is `linkDelete`. But when you build the link using Html.ActionLink, You are passing a parameter named `ID`!

Change it to match with your method signature.

```
Html.ActionLink("امحاء", "Delete", new { linkDelete = item.ID });
```

Comment: error is:   The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Admin/Dashboard/Delete

Comment: Do you have this delete action method in your dashboard controller under admin area ?

Comment: thanks,i solved it! i puted [httpPost] before action Delete ! and it had error

Comment: Cool! I suggest to always make action methods which deletes stuff to be HttpPost action so that some user simply won't navigate to your delete action via browser and delete stuff. When you do that, you need to change the link to a form submit (HttpPost method)